# why isn't removeFromSuperview removing my movie subview? Xcode

Tags: objective-c, video, nsnotification

I'm trying to get a movie that plays to dismiss on its own without having to hit the "Done" button. I think it's a recent iOS 6 problem since I'm following a tutorial exactly and when I insert NSLogs the NSNotification and removeFromSuperview are being recognized but the movie stays there once it has ended. Here's my code, please help:

```
    - (IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:@"RomneyFlipSequence1" ofType:@"mov"]];
    _moviePlayer =
    [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
     initWithContentURL:url];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:_moviePlayer];

    _moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    _moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
    [_moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:NO];
}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {

    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:player];

    if ([player
         respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
    {
    [player.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: did you fix this problem I have the same problem.

Comment: Yes, it's a problem with leaving full screen. This line needs to be added:

player.fullscreen = NO;
[player.view removeFromSuperview];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You entered the player into fullscreen mode.

```
[_moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:NO];
```

Reading other solutions in SO it seems that when you press "Done" the player is taken out of fullscreen first, and then the notification is thrown. After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16083178/162059), adding

```
[_moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
```

before your `removeFromSuperview` call will solve your problem.

If the above doesn't work, in addition you may try stoping the player first so the full code will be

```
-(void)removePlayer:(MPMoviePlayerController *)player{

    NSLog(@"Playback Finished");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:_moviePlayer];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:_moviePlayer];

    [_moviePlayer stop]; // <-- May not be needed
    if ([_moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
    {
        [_moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
        [_moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];

    }

    _moviePlayer=nil;



}
```

I use the same method for both notifications "Done" and "PlayBackFinished"

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You had added `_moviePlayer.view` as a view and you are trying to remove `player.view`

i think this will do it :

```
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:player];

if ([player
     respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
{
[_moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

}

Comment: Still the same, the movie does not dismiss. I was hoping this fix would work but since player = _moviePlayer in that first line, I guess it's the same thing. The problem does seem to be with the last line though.